# How to print % as a character in printf

Tags: bash

I would like to use % as a normal character in printf lets say the output is a is 20% higher than b how would I be able to do that since % is used as a special character?

Comment: Try using it double `"%%"`. This is as in its parent C `printf` function.

Comment: thanks did not knew it is the same as in C

Comment: @SureshKoya This should not be marked as a duplicate of that C question. This question is about bash even though the answer is basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use double %

```
printf  "hello%%"
```

Comment: The OP is not asking about C, but the shell `printf` tool, that in the end also accepts the double %.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape it using `%%`.

```
printf "100%%\n"
```